# JQuery: How to attach same delegated event simultaneously on different element and different actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates

Is there any way to do some like:

```
$("#parent").on(
    'click', 
    {
        'tr': function(){
            //do stuff one
        }, 
        'img[name="print"]': function(){
            //do stuff two
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance, but it didn't work propertly and I only want to write less.

Comment: I don't know what's hierarchy in your DOM, but be careful about propagation if for example `<img/>` is inside `<tr/>`

Comment: Yes, it is inside of <tr/> but any <img/> tag was created on firing event click on <tr/> tag, this is the reason because I need to attach the event as delegated of table#parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't believe that is available.  If you want to be less verbose, I think the best thing you can do is to chain your events like so:

```
$("#parent").on('click','tr',someFunction).on('click','img',someOtherFunction);
```